# How to preserve the element order when saving a django JSONField

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm writing a small app that saves JSON verified by a schema to a PostgreSQL DB using Django's `JSONField` class. I am relying on the data to keep nodes in order but`JSONField` apparently uses PostgreSQL's jsonb type, which reorders the JSON data to increase indexing performance.

Is there a way to preserve the order of elements using this method by forcing the `json` type instead of `jsonb`? Or should I give up and look into a different database's JSON support?

Samples:

What I send to the DB to be saved:

```
"Item": {
            "@id": "blah"
            "ItemComponent": {
                "Weapon": {
                    "@blah": "blah"
                    "WeaponFlags": {
                        "@blah": "blah"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Flags": {
                "@blah": "blah",
            }
        }
```

How it is saved to the Database:

```
"Item": {
            "@id": "blah"
            "Flags": {
                "@blah": "blah",
            },
            "ItemComponent": {
                "Weapon": {
                    "@blah": "blah"
                    "WeaponFlags": {
                        "@blah": "blah"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not possible (at least in MySQL) coz this is a kind of *feature* to optimize the querying.

Comment: Yeah I read that just then, disappointing because I didn't want to have to write out all the fields I have to consume (Which is about 400) when I have them all defined in a JSON schema

Comment: Create the field in the table as a varchar and just send the JSON as a string.

Comment: Why does your schema checking depend on the order of the elements?  Personally, I would try to spend my time overcoming that obstacle.

Comment: This is turned into xml for a downstream system to consume. The xml is checked against a schema and fails if the nodes are in the wrong order. I have no control over the downstream system, otherwise I would change the schema to not care about the order.